# Saving a two-d list to a file in python 2.7 changes the list?

Tags: python-2.7

I would like to save my list to a file after adding a new name to it. The main issue is that if I save using:

```
money =  [['Amber', '87000000000'], ['Theo', '15'], ['Duncan', '0'], ['Russell', '0'], ['Lauren', '0'], ['Sandra', '0']]
finaldata = ""
for row in money:
    data  = " ".join(map(str,row))
    finaldata = str(finaldata) + str(data) + "\n"

f1 = open('bank.txt', 'w')
print >> f1, finaldata
f1.close()

with open("bank.txt") as textFile:
    money = [line.split() for line in textFile]
```

It creates an extra position in the list. Before the list is saved it looks exactly as it should, therefore I know the issue is something to do with the code that saves the list to the file.

The result should save the list like this:

```
[['Amber', '87000000000'], ['Theo', '15'], ['Duncan', '0'], ['Russell', '0'], ['Lauren', '0'], ['Sandra', '0']]
```

But instead prints it like this:

```
[['Amber', '87000000000'], ['Theo', '15'], ['Duncan', '0'], ['Russell', '0'], ['Lauren', '0'], ['Sandra', '0'], []]
```

I have tried another method (Without the "\n") and this also saves it wrong. Like with the attempt before the name is added to the list correctly but saving using the code:

```
money =  [['Amber', '87000000000'], ['Theo', '15'], ['Duncan', '0'], ['Russell', '0'], ['Lauren', '0'], ['Sandra', '0']]
finaldata = ""
for row in money:
    data  = " ".join(map(str,row))
    finaldata = str(finaldata) + str(data)

f1 = open('bank.txt', 'w')
print >> f1, finaldata
f1.close()

with open("bank.txt") as textFile:
    money = [line.split() for line in textFile]
```

Makes the list look like this:

```
[['Amber', '87000000000Theo', '15Duncan', '0Russell', '0Lauren', '0Sandra', '0']]
```

Can anyone help me understand where I am going wrong? I have been working on  this one piece of code for several hours now.

Comment: You need to get rid of the extra newlines ("\n") at the end of the script. Otherwise you will have empty entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to avoid the extra `\n` at the end of your array.

```
money =  [['Amber', '87000000000'], ['Theo', '15'], ['Duncan', '0'], ['Russell', '0'], ['Lauren', '0'], ['Sandra', '0']]
finaldata = []
for row in money:
    data  = " ".join(map(str,row))
    finaldata.append(str(data))

f1 = open('bank.txt', 'w')
print >> f1, "\n".join(finaldata)
f1.close()
```

Observe that I make use of `join` to chain the `finaldata` array into a single string with `\n`.